# Azure Infrastructure as code project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, templates, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I am not sure with project template to use in my Visual Studio. And the existing one throws and object reference error.

I am using VS 2015 with latest SDK, would 2017 make a difference?

[image]

[image]

this error exists in VS 2017 , VS 2015 and tried in different machines. Different projects. After the number of projects are growing we are getting this error.

Comment: Could you please tell me your azure SDK version and VS version? I have created a test demo on my computer, it works well. If possible, I suggest you could install the newest azure SDK and try to create again. SDK download [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/)

Comment: In my test machine, both VS2015 and VS2017 could create azure template project. Could you please explain more about how you get this error? Do you mean you get this error when you just created the project? If possible please post more details steps for us to repro this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is *usually* a problem with the installation of the SDK.  You can try uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK.  Go to Control Panel>Programs and Features - search for all the entries with "Microsoft Azure Tools Visual Studio" and uninstall them.  The go back to the Web Platform Installer and re-install the latest SDK.

LMK how it goes...

Comment: this error exists in VS 2017 , VS 2015 and tried in different machines.

Comment: Send me an email and we can try to debug that way... bmoore at microsoft.com